# Remove chars from the string

Tags: c++

To remove set of chars from a given string, i have implemented this function.

```
    void removeChars (string& str, const string& chars)
{
    vector <bool> v (256, false);
    for (int i=0; i < chars.size(); ++i)
    {
            v[chars[i]] = true;

    }

    int k=0;

    for (int j=0; j < str.size(); ++j)
    {
            if (v[str[j]]==false)
            {
                    str[k] = str[j];
                    ++k;
            }

    }
    str[k] = '\0';

}
```

But after processing the string from this function. Its printing some garbage value.

```
string s1 = "trying to remove chars from string";
string s2 = "tr";
removeChars2 (s1, s2);
```

Now print s1

```
ying o emove chas fom sing string
Expected : ying o emove chas fom sing
```

is there anything wrong in this implementation.

Comment: What is the problem? I don't see any obvious "garbage values"? It helps a lot if you describe both the output you're getting *and* the output you expected

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal add `str.erase(k);` at the end of the RemoveChars function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add terminator character for `std::string`, it keeps track of the string end in other ways.

Instead of modifying `str` directly, I would recommend you append characters to a new string, and then copy that string to `str` when done.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. But it was asked to modify the original string. No extra space is allowed.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Then you might be interested in the [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) method of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 2):

Use STL algorithms, and you don't have to reimplement everything :)

```
string text("trying to remove chars from string");
char toRemove[] = "tr";

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(toRemove); ++i)
    text.erase(std::remove(text.begin(), text.end(), toRemove[i]), text.end());

std::cout << text << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.resize(k);` instead of `str[k] = '\0';`

Comment: Its working fine with resize(k). my thought is it shouldn't be resize(k-1) ? because there is no char at kth place.